# How to move an image in picturebox using mouse events

Tags: c#, .net, picturebox

i am trying to move a image in picture box. i added panel to my application and also added picture box in panel. i opened an image.if the image size is big.i want to see the particular portion of image. so how can i move the image up and down (without using scroll bars) to see the particular portion of image?

Comment: PictureBox was not made to make panning an image easy.  Move the PictureBox instead, just change its Location property.

Comment: Don't use tags containing phrase 'csharp' just because you writing your application on C#. Use only necessary tags instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add controls like move left, move right, move up, move down with associated actions to move the image within your picturebox. An example of how to do this for moving the image to the right is shown below. You can implement these action with mouse down and mouse up events so that the user just presses the appropriate buttons to move the picture as he wants. Also note that once you reach the maximum dimensions of the image, you can change the rectangular region to that within image bounds.

```
int ff = 0; //number of positions to move
Bitmap b2;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ff == 0) { b2 = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);}  //original image as bitmap b2
    Bitmap b1 = new Bitmap(pictureBox1 .Width ,pictureBox1.Height );  //new bitmap with rectangular region of original image
    Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(ff++, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height );
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b1);
    g.DrawImage(b2, 0, 0, r1, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    g.Dispose();
    pictureBox1.Image = null;
    pictureBox1.Image = (Image)b1;
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it really answers your question, but this seems like a fun reason to play with [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609). [This video](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/j.van.gogh/writing-your-first-rx-application) demonstrates nicely how well this stuff works with asynchronous events like mouse-input.